# Refactor a switch statement with cyclomatic complexity

Tags: swift, swiftlint

Currently i am getting the warning "Cyclomatic Complexity Violation: Function should have complexity 8 or less: currently complexity equals 9 (cyclomatic_complexity)"

I want to refactor it so it doesn't show the warning anymore

My code is below

Comment: "My code is below" No it isn't.

Comment: First of all, that's not a switch. Second, why did you delete your code ?

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to ignore the error message, you can use this line in .swiftlint.yml. But on the other hand you can prefer switch case and enum structure for functions in postImageViewModel.

```
# .swiftlint.yml
 cyclomatic_complexity: 20
```